# Rank instances by missing amount in descending order

Tags: r

I want to sort this dataset as **(rank instances by missing amount in descending order)**

can someone help me how to do it in R language , is there any command to do it in r .

```
 df=data.frame(x=c(1,4,6,NA,7,NA,9,10,4,NA),
          y=c(10,12,NA,NA,14,18,20,15,12,17),
          z=c(225,198,NA,NA,NA,130,NA,200,NA,99),
          v=c(44,51,NA,NA,45,NA,25,36,75,NA))

df
    x  y   z  v
1   1 10 225 44
2   4 12 198 51
3   6 NA  NA NA
4  NA NA  NA NA
5   7 14  NA 45
6  NA 18 130 NA
7   9 20  NA 25
8  10 15 200 36
9   4 12  NA 75
10 NA 17  99 NA
```

I want to get this result :

```
   x  y   z  v
4  NA NA  NA NA
3  6  NA  NA NA   
6  NA 18 130 NA
10 NA 17  99 NA
5  7  14  NA 45
7  9  20  NA 25
9  4  12  NA 75
1  1  10 225 44
2  4  12 198 51
8  10 15 200 36
```

Comment: Can you please provide expected result, as well as what you've tried so far?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Probably something along the lines of `df[ order(rowSums(is.na(df)), descending=TRUE), ]`

Comment: @42- , I run your code but it is give me this result                                              `df[ order(rowSums(is.na(df)), descending=TRUE), ]
Error in order(rowSums(is.na(df)), descending = TRUE) : 
  argument lengths differ `

Comment: @docendodiscimus , HubertL   .  see my question this is my expected output .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my comment I incorrectly remembered the name of the argument for changing the direction of an `order` result. The fix is simply to use the correct name:

```
> df[ order(rowSums(is.na(df)), decreasing=TRUE), ]
    x  y   z  v
4  NA NA  NA NA
3   6 NA  NA NA
6  NA 18 130 NA
10 NA 17  99 NA
5   7 14  NA 45
7   9 20  NA 25
9   4 12  NA 75
1   1 10 225 44
2   4 12 198 51
8  10 15 200 36
```

Comment: 42-  thank you  for your answer  that is very helpful .